# Sending a command to the server with a fabric mod

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

How do I send a command to the server like "/msg someone some important event happened!" using a fabric mod in Minecraft 1.20.1?

I haven't been able to find any code to try out that is not using classes that do not exist anymore.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to use
`new CommandDispatcher<S>().execute(commandString, source);`
where commandString is the command which you want to execute(e.g. `"/kill @e"`
) and source is an object of type `S` - for example if you are doing this from a command, you would do 
`new CommandDispatcher<CommandContext<ServerCommandSource>>.execute("/kill @e", myCommandContext)`